# How do can I get the variables I made in another object

Tags: java, oop

For example I have the Platform class:

```
public class Platform
{
   double x, y;
   Color c;

   public Platform(double x, double y, Color c)
   {
      this.x = x;
      this.y = y;
      this.c = c;
   }
}
```

And I am trying to access it's parameters after creating a new instance of the Platform class in a whole other class. Variable 'x' will be changing for context:

```
   public void makePlatform() {  
      int x = 100; 
      int y = 800;
      Color c; 
      c = new Color(1,1,1); //platform is black
      Platform p = new Platform(x,y, c);
   }
```

Now here is me trying to access variable 'x' in another method in the same class:

```
public void run() {
while(true) {
if(right)
    p.x++;

 if(left)
    p.x--;

 if (p.x > 335 || p.x < 0) {
    p.x = -p.x;
 }
 }
}
```

I know the initialization is in another scope, I don't know how to use what I created in another method.

Thanks

Comment: Add a `getX()` and a `getY()` method to class `Platform`. Or did I misunderstand your question?

Comment: How can I access/make them visible in my method?

Comment: Can you [edit] your question and post a [mcve] ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Platform p = new Platform(x,y, c);`. here `p` is a local variable inside `makePlatform()`, you can not access it outside the method.

To access `p` outside the method, declare it outside  `makePlatform()`

```
 Platform p 
 public void makePlatform() {  
      int x = 100; 
      int y = 800;
      Color c; 
      c = new Color(1,1,1); //platform is black
      p = new Platform(x,y, c);
      rightOrLeft( p );
   }
```

Now you can access `p` outside the method

Answer (score 0):

For another method:  normally you pass it in as a parameter.  (And yes, adding setters and getters would be the better option rather than accessing a field directly.)

```
public void rightOrLeft( Platform p ) {
  if(right)
     p.x++;
  if(left)
     p.x--;

  if (p.x > 335 || p.x < 0) {
     p.x = -p.x;
  }
}
```

And then to set this up:

```
   public void makePlatform() {  
      int x = 100; 
      int y = 800;
      Color c; 
      c = new Color(1,1,1); //platform is black
      Platform p = new Platform(x,y, c);
      rightOrLeft( p );
   }
```

Comment: Why would I need to have `( Platform p )` in the rightOrLeft method (run method in my case). Can I avoid this by having setters and getters in the `Platform` class?

Comment: You use formal parameters like `Platform p` so you can bind (use) any Platform variable there.  It's very handy.  While you can use instance fields as upog suggested, method parameters like this are generally considered better if they meet your requirements.